# Java Append Key Input to String

Tags: java, string, input, keyboard, key

For my current project I need to create a custom text box that gets each key pressed and adds it to a string. I'm constantly updating the method that retrieves the key a user is pressing and then I add it like so:

```
public void addCharacter(String c) {
    String before = text;
    String after = before;

    if (!before.endsWith(c)) {
     after = text + c;
    } else {
      //What can I do here to check if the key 
      //was released and then pressed again, so that 
      //it only adds the character the number of times the user presses the key.
    }   
    text = after;
}
```

My problem is that if I type a key it adds tons of them because of the fact that it is constantly updating, which is why I had to check if it's the same letter as before, and not add it.

EDIT:
Example of how we add the key:

```
if (key.a) {
   addCharacter("a"); 
   return; 
}
```

Comment: Is `text` a global variable?

Comment: yeess... it works fine except for the problem I described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the job done by using a [`KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). This is basically a listener which sends events each time a key is typed, pressed and released. In a nutshell, I would listen to a `keyPressed` event and then I would not type that letter until I receive a `keyReleased` event.

Comment: Yeah I'm just not sure what would happen if I had multiple instance of text box, would it still work the same way?

Comment: Well, if you have multiple text boxes what would happen I guess is that if you hold the key and click on another text box it still won't be written in the other one since the key os still pressed.